# Apply validation before Data Transform

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I want to transform a text field that I got from submitted user data to an Object in Symfony2. I used DataTransformer in order to do this. When I use built-in validators like 'NotEmpty' or 'NotNull' or any custom validators that built in standard way Symfony2 passes my specific object to them but I want to validate this text field before converting it to object. What should I do? (sry if my English is not so good)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Validation are always done on the reverse transformed data.

The best way to add validation rule before the transformation occurred is to use an event listener or subscriber on `FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT`.

You'll get the raw data. Just apply your validation logic here then use the `$event->getForm()->get('xxxx')->addError()` method to add errors on the corresponding field.

More informations on event subscribers / listeners :

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/form_events.html#event-listeners
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/form_events.html#event-subscribers

Comment: What if I want to do it in standard way? I want to reuse this form element in many different applications.

Comment: I will go for a custom `FormType` that extends `TextType` and only add the `DataTransformer` and the `EventSubscriber` inside its `build` method. You can add a `pre_validators` option that will contain a list of validators passed to the constructor of your `EventSubscriber` and used to check the raw data. @see http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html

Comment: @rolebi Look this [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16168694/adding-a-form-error-in-an-eventlistener).
They say that you cannot addError on a children, because it will be clear and the error will not show on the form. That currently my case and i don't find solution about it.